# What is the most efficient way of extracting these integers from a string using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, text-extraction

I have a table (in a SQL server 2014 database, accessed via SSMS) of engineering data, and I need to report the bolt lengths that are mentioned in a description field, marked in bold:

```
STUD BOLT SET, SANS 1700, GR 8.8, SANS 1700, GR 8, GALVANISED (8 X M24 X 140 LG C/W 1 NUT, 12 X M24 X 170 LG C/W 1 NUT)
STUD BOLT SET, SANS 1700, GR 8.8, SANS 1700, GR 8, GALVANISED (2 X M20 X 80 LG C/W 1 NUT, 6 X M20 X 90 LG C/W 1 NUT)
STUD BOLT SET, SANS 1700, GR 8.8, SANS 1700, GR 8, GALVANISED (8 X M24 X 130 LG C/W 1 NUT, 12 X M24 X 150 LG C/W 1 NUT)
STUD BOLT SET, ASME B1.1, ASTM A193 B7, ASME B1.1, ASTM A194 GR 2H, GALVANISED (28 x 1 3/4" UN8 x 270 LG C/W 1 NUT)
```

Note that there are two bolt lengths mentioned in the description (eg the first record has "140 LG" and "170 LG"), but I only need the second one, "170", which is also always the larger of the two. While the position of the number should remain a fixed length from the end of the string, the length varies between two and three digits.

So beyond using MID(string,15,3) inside a lot of nested if statements to determine the length and position of the number, I don't really know how best to go about doing this.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also, you should be clear about what "efficient" means; for the system (performance) or for the programmer (convenient)?

Comment: My first thought might seem a little odd.  Taking it step by step: `reverse(string)` reverses all the letters in the string.  Then `CHARINDEX(' GL ', reverse(string))` tells you where the *last* LG is found (note the reversal of the search string).  Then `len(string) - CHARINDEX(' GL ', reverse(string))` tells you where the final LG is in the original string.  Then `mid(string, len(string) - CHARINDEX(' GL ', reverse(string)) - 3, 3)` is either the 3 digits, or a space followed by 2 digits.  Add a trim (or maybe ltrim) and you've got it.  Note: Untested, but the approach seems right.

Comment: There are so many examples of this kind of thing out there that I am very surprised you didn't find something similar to help you get started.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. Beyond MS Access my SQL abilities are fairly limited. Apologies for the ambiguity of my post. I just didn't know where to start. I'm using SSMS, and the database is on SQL server 2014.

Comment: @Bohemian I guess by "efficient" I mean the least number of steps. So yes programmatically convenient. I realize there's a multitude of ways to achieve this, and everyone will have their own opinion of which way is the most efficient. Performance in this case is not a factor.

Comment: @DaleK yes I have no doubt there are solutions out there, but with my limited knowledge they all seem quite opaque to me in regards to how I apply the solution to my data. As I am very limited on time, I had to seek a more direct solution in this case.

Comment: "seek a more direct solution in this case" Did you find one?  I see you haven't accepted either of the proposed solutions, nor commented on the one I proposed.

Comment: Requiring an urgent solution isn't something this site caters for.

Comment: I can seek an urgent solution, doesn't mean I expect it or feel I am entitled to it. Considering this is my first ever question and I'm finding my feet on the etiquette here, the gatekeeping and unwelcoming attitude is baffling. I appreciate all the constructive criticism of my question and ill do better next time.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @DavidWohlferd I only just finished implementing Yitzhaks solution and have marking it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution that is using *tokenization* via XML and XQuery.

The desired value is not in the same position from the end of the string due to edge cases.

That's why, first, we will find a position of the bolt length using if/else logic.

After that the XPath predicate `/root/r[last() - sql:column("t2.position")]` does the job.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens NVARCHAR(1024));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('STUD BOLT SET, SANS 1700, GR 8.8, SANS 1700, GR 8, GALVANISED (8 X M24 X 140 LG C/W 1 NUT, 12 X M24 X 170 LG C/W 1 NUT)'),
('STUD BOLT SET, SANS 1700, GR 8.8, SANS 1700, GR 8, GALVANISED (2 X M20 X 80 LG C/W 1 NUT, 6 X M20 X 90 LG C/W 1 NUT)'),
('STUD BOLT SET, SANS 1700, GR 8.8, SANS 1700, GR 8, GALVANISED (8 X M24 X 130 LG C/W 1 NUT, 12 X M24 X 150 LG C/W 1 NUT)'),
('STUD BOLT SET, ASME B1.1, ASTM A193 B7, ASME B1.1, ASTM A194 GR 2H, GALVANISED (28 x 1 3/4" UN8 x 270 LG C/W 1 NUT)'),
('STUD BOLT SET, ASME B1.1, ASTM A193 B7, ASME B1.1, ASTM A194 GR 2H (12 x 7/8" x 110 LG C/W NUT)')
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT *
    , bolt_length = c.value('(/root/r[last() - sql:column("t2.position")]/text())[1]', 'INT')
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.query('if (/root/r[last() - 1]/text() = "1") then 4
    else 3').value('.','INT')) AS t2(position);
```

**Output**

| id | tokens | bolt_length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | STUD BOLT SET, SANS 1700, GR 8.8, SANS 1700, GR 8, GALVANISED (8 X M24 X 140 LG C/W 1 NUT, 12 X M24 X 170 LG C/W 1 NUT) | 170 |
| 2 | STUD BOLT SET, SANS 1700, GR 8.8, SANS 1700, GR 8, GALVANISED (2 X M20 X 80 LG C/W 1 NUT, 6 X M20 X 90 LG C/W 1 NUT) | 90 |
| 3 | STUD BOLT SET, SANS 1700, GR 8.8, SANS 1700, GR 8, GALVANISED (8 X M24 X 130 LG C/W 1 NUT, 12 X M24 X 150 LG C/W 1 NUT) | 150 |
| 4 | STUD BOLT SET, ASME B1.1, ASTM A193 B7, ASME B1.1, ASTM A194 GR 2H, GALVANISED (28 x 1 3/4" UN8 x 270 LG C/W 1 NUT) | 270 |
| 5 | STUD BOLT SET, ASME B1.1, ASTM A193 B7, ASME B1.1, ASTM A194 GR 2H (12 x 7/8" x 110 LG C/W NUT) | 110 |

Comment: I appreciate your reply, i will noodle with this. Cheers

Comment: This is brilliant and almost works perfectly, but there are a couple of instances where the index of the bolt_length changes because the "1" in "1 NUT" is missing. How do I ignore these or handle the error? example of record that fails the query: "STUD BOLT SET, ASME B1.1, ASTM A193 B7, ASME B1.1, ASTM A194 GR 2H (12 x 7/8" x 110 LG C/W NUT)"

Comment: Wow, perfect. You are an absolute legend mate. I cant thank you enough. I'd upvote if I could. Solved!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `ssms` tag means you are on SQL server, you have only limited support to some version of regular expression (not the POSIX regex).
The below query will do what you want. Its principle is to locate the rightmost occurrence of `LG` and from there, the 2nd preceding space. The result you want is between these 2 positions.
Refer to the comments for explanation, remove the CTE included to have a complete example and cast the returned value to integer yourself if needed:

```sql
WITH MyTable(description) AS (
SELECT 'STUD BOLT SET, SANS 1700, GR 8.8, SANS 1700, GR 8, GALVANISED (8 X M24 X 140 LG C/W 1 NUT, 12 X M24 X 170 LG C/W 1 NUT)'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'STUD BOLT SET, SANS 1700, GR 8.8, SANS 1700, GR 8, GALVANISED (2 X M20 X 80 LG C/W 1 NUT, 6 X M20 X 90 LG C/W 1 NUT)'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'STUD BOLT SET, SANS 1700, GR 8.8, SANS 1700, GR 8, GALVANISED (8 X M24 X 130 LG C/W 1 NUT, 12 X M24 X 150 LG C/W 1 NUT)'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'STUD BOLT SET, ASME B1.1, ASTM A193 B7, ASME B1.1, ASTM A194 GR 2H, GALVANISED (28 x 1 3/4" UN8 x 270 LG C/W 1 NUT)'
)
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(description, LEN(description) - pos1 - pos2, pos2 - 1)
FROM MyTable
/* REVERSE the string so that searching for the rightmost character/pattern will be equivalent to searching the leftmost character/reversed pattern in the reversed string */
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REVERSE(description)) AS rev(revDescription) 
/* Find the rightmost occurrence of 'LG', by searching the leftmost occurrence of 'GL' in the reserved string */
CROSS APPLY (SELECT patindex(REVERSE(N'% % LG%'), revDescription)) AS ca1(pos1)
/* Skipping the L (from LG) and its preceding space (i.e. starting on character 3), find the rightmost space */
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(revDescription, pos1 + 3, 1000))) AS ca2(pos2)
```

Other databases may have better support for regular expression, making the query much easier to write. Below is an example with Postgres, we can get it done in 1 line; a similar approach may work with other databases too.

```sql
WITH MyTable(description) AS (
SELECT 'STUD BOLT SET, SANS 1700, GR 8.8, SANS 1700, GR 8, GALVANISED (8 X M24 X 140 LG C/W 1 NUT, 12 X M24 X 170 LG C/W 1 NUT)'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'STUD BOLT SET, SANS 1700, GR 8.8, SANS 1700, GR 8, GALVANISED (2 X M20 X 80 LG C/W 1 NUT, 6 X M20 X 90 LG C/W 1 NUT)'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'STUD BOLT SET, SANS 1700, GR 8.8, SANS 1700, GR 8, GALVANISED (8 X M24 X 130 LG C/W 1 NUT, 12 X M24 X 150 LG C/W 1 NUT)'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'STUD BOLT SET, ASME B1.1, ASTM A193 B7, ASME B1.1, ASTM A194 GR 2H, GALVANISED (28 x 1 3/4" UN8 x 270 LG C/W 1 NUT)'
)
SELECT UNNEST(regexp_matches(description, '(\d+)\s*LG(?!LG)'))
FROM MyTable
```

In this case, we capture the number (`(\d+)`) before `LG`. `(?!LG)` is a negative lookahead, which means there cannot be allowed another occurrence of `LG` to the right of the one we want to capture.
If you were to remove `(?!LG)` (as well as the `UNNEST`), you would get all the numbers immediately preceding all the occurrences of `LG` in 1 array per input string.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your detailed reply, I will give these a go.